# How to know the filepath of files created by App

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am creating a file "abc.txt" and storing the data. How can I know where is the data stored in SD card, I don't have a Android phone

```
  try {
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("abc.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
 String s = "Data to be written ok fine cool";fos.write(s.getBytes());
 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want that file so that I can sattach it and send as email in background

Comment: are you sure it is on sdCard...... because looks you not used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not written to the SD card. Your file is written to the private data area on the phone where your application's private files are written. If you want to know where that is (it is different on different devices), you can get that using

```
String whereAreMyFiles = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score -1):

As Dheeresh Singh said there is no place it got placed to. You haven't given it a proper location. This is an answer.

Comment: That isn't true. It got written to the application's private data area.